# Правописание числительных в документообороте

Tags: числительные

*Предоставить отпуск продолжительностью 21 (двадцати одного) календарных дня.*

Правильно ли так писать в приказе?

Comment: Похожий вопрос: http://forum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=4482. Ответ: продолжительностью двадцать один календарный день.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно:

> Предоставить отпуск продолжительностью двадцать один календарный день.

Answer (score 2):

*Предоставить отпуск продолжительностью 21 (двадцати одного) календарных дня.
Правильно ли так писать в приказе?*

Нет, неправильно(!) — ни в приказе, ни в каком-либо другом тексте.
Числительные по правилам русского языка согласуются с существительными таким образом:

**Один** (одна, одно) — именительный падеж (**день**, собака, окно);
**два** (две), **три, четыре** — родительный падеж (**дня**, собаки, окна);
**пять - двадцать** — родительный падеж множественного числа (**дней**, собак, окон).

В числительных, которые больше двадцати, согласованию подлежит только число единиц:
двадцать ***один день***, двадцать ***одна собака***, двадцать ***одно окно*.**

Правильно будет так:
*Предоставить отпуск продолжительностью двадцать **один** календарный **день***.